# how apply str.contain to every column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like this :
[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8B6Y.png)

I want to apply this func to all column of the dataframe:

```
data3 = data2.str.contains('|'.join(features))
```

but i got error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

“features is a list of word”

how i can do this and solve this problem?

Comment: Could you share a part of your data here? and what is features in your code.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR features is list of words, and data just like screenshot a full of sentences

Comment: Maybe this could help: `data2.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(features)))`. But it's difficult without the data to come up with a solution.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR tnx its work but its return True and False ; I want to return sentences have features word

Comment: Then maybe `data2[data2.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(features)))]`.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe doesn't have a `contains` method, but the columns do. Iterate the columns and assign to the result.

```
feature_str = '|'.join(features)
data3 = pd.DataFrame()
for name, col in data2.items():
    data3[name] = col.str.contains(feature_str)
```

Comment: tnx its work but its return True and False ; I want to return sentences have features word